# Почему в Ruby "из коробки" отсутствует возможность преобразования false/true к Integer?

Tags: ruby

Пару дней назад начал изучать Ruby в качестве замены Паскалю для школьных/олимпиадных задач (уж очень я ленивый, чтобы почти в каждой программе писать заново тот же qsort и прочие нужные вещи, которых нет в Паскале изначально).
При этом меня крайне удивило отсутствие такой, казалось бы, обычной вещи как преобразование `False-/TrueClass` к `Integer`:

```
# условие (input % 2 != ... ) всегда истинно, ибо <число> != false
if (input % 2 != (string == "Odd")) then print "Wrong input" end 
# >> "false can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)"
i += (i / 9 == 8)
```

Отсюда такой вопрос: почему создатели языка "урезали" эту возможность по умолчанию?

---

P.S. Сам для подобного преобразования пользуюсь небольшим хаком (для "чистого" Ruby):

```
zero = (false.object_id / 2)   # ==> 0
one  = (true.object_id  / 2)   # ==> 1
```

(в основе лежит тот факт, что для `false` *object_id* всегда равен 0, а для `true` - 2, т.е. поделив эти значения на 2 получим привычные нам 0 и 1).
Может быть есть еще какие-то способы, буду благодарен, если поделитесь (имею в виду, так сказать, inline-способы, т.е. без написания расширений для False-/TrueClass).

Comment: Мой ответ был неверный =\

Comment: Можно подробней о самой задаче?

Comment: А я его проверил на false и был уже рад :)  
Да нет, никакой конкретной задачи нет, просто вот такое ограничение само по себе заинтересовало.

Comment: Мне и самому интересно стало, как это сделать без костылей. Хотя никода не приходилось сталкиваться с такой проблемой, да и не для этих целей Boolean введен =)

Comment: Это у меня привычка еще с Си, да и не люблю лишние команды писать, когда все одним действием можно. Да и Ruby вроде бы как раз по такой идеологии и спроектирован.

Answer (score 1):

> (в основе лежит тот факт, что для false object_id всегда равен 0, а для true - 2, т.е. поделив эти значения на 2 получим привычные нам 0 и 1).

Необязательно. Например если использовать Rubinius:

```
rubinius-2.0.0dev :001 > true.object_id
 => 18 
rubinius-2.0.0dev :002 > false.object_id
 => 10
```

Как уже сказали, в Ruby `true` и `false` -- отдельные объекты. Вообще, всё кроме `false` и `nil` в условниках трактуется как `true` (и `0` тоже)

И вообще, лучше писать вот так (более руби-стиль):

```
puts "Wrong input" if 2.odd? and string != "Odd"
```

Comment: Не знал про Rubinius, но это все-таки уже другое.  
Насчет `if 2.odd? and string != "Odd"` - у меня в примере проверяется, сходится ли введенное число (input) с его "описанием".  
Над стилем работаю, пока по сишному получается :)

Answer (score 0):

В Ruby и **false** и **true** и **любое число** - это всё объекты классов.

Первый способ:
Вместо:

```
if (input % 2 != (string == "Odd")) then print "Wrong input" end
```

Попробуй:

```
input.odd?
```

Второй способ, но не рекомендую им увлекаться, потому что поведение базовых объектов Руби становиться непредсказуемым:

**false** есть объектом класса **FalseClass**.
Ты можешь переопределить возвращаемое значение,  метода **to_s**, чтобы в твоём случае **false** при вычислении возвращал число "0":

```
class FalseClass
  def to_s
    return 0
  end
end
```

[РубиДок в помощь](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/FalseClass.html)

Спасибо,
Сергей

Comment: Да, но  
>  if (input % 2 != (string == "Odd"))  
  
был сферический в вакууме пример, первое что в голову пришло.  
И потом - в том то и фишка, что я не хочу писать костыли к стандартным классам.

Comment: Я считаю, что Руби сомодостаточный язык. Если вопрос не есть прикладной проблематики, то что-то подобное обсуждалось здесь http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/60154

Comment: @sdemian я читал эту дискуссию и, честно говоря, не увидел там ничего по теме моего вопроса.